# SNMP MIB ERROR scalar's parent node must be simple node Object Not Imported

Tags: snmp, mib, oid

I have the following file and I get

> X-MIB.txt:26: scalar's parent node must be simple node Object Not
>   Imported
>
> X-MIB.txt:35: scalar's parent node must be simple node Object Not
>   Imported
>
> X-MIB.txt:45: scalar's parent node must be simple node Object Not
>   Imported
>
> X-MIB.txt:55: scalar's parent node must be simple node Object Not
>   Imported

Here's the MIB file (after emitting my company name and replacing names with "x" and "y")

```
X-MIB DEFINITIONS ::= BEGIN

IMPORTS
    MODULE-IDENTITY, OBJECT-TYPE, NOTIFICATION-TYPE, Integer32 FROM SNMPv2-SMI
    DisplayString                           FROM RFC1213-MIB
    OBJECT-GROUP, NOTIFICATION-GROUP        FROM SNMPv2-CONF
    y                                       FROM Y-MIB;

x MODULE-IDENTITY
       LAST-UPDATED "201411060000Z"
       ORGANIZATION "Y Corporation"
       CONTACT-INFO
       "Y Corporation
        www.y.com"
       DESCRIPTION
       "The Structure of Management Information for the Y X enterprise."
       REVISION      "201411060000Z"
       DESCRIPTION
         "Initial version of this MIB."
       ::= { y 101 }

-- 1.3.6.1.4.1.1139.101.1
xAlert OBJECT IDENTIFIER ::= { x 1 }

-- 1.3.6.1.4.1.1139.101.1.1
xAlertSeverity OBJECT-TYPE
       SYNTAX Integer32
       MAX-ACCESS accessible-for-notify
       STATUS current
       DESCRIPTION
        "Severity of the event"
        ::= { xAlert 1 }

-- 1.3.6.1.4.1.1139.101.1.2
xAlertType OBJECT-TYPE
       SYNTAX DisplayString (SIZE (0..255))
       MAX-ACCESS accessible-for-notify
       STATUS current
       DESCRIPTION
        "Type of the alert"
        ::= { xAlert 2 }


-- 1.3.6.1.4.1.1139.101.1.3
xAlertSourceObjectId OBJECT-TYPE
       SYNTAX DisplayString (SIZE (0..255))
       MAX-ACCESS accessible-for-notify
       STATUS current
       DESCRIPTION
        "Object id for which the alert was created"
        ::= { xAlert 3 }


-- 1.3.6.1.4.1.1139.101.1.4
xAlertActionCode OBJECT-TYPE
       SYNTAX DisplayString (SIZE (0..255))
       MAX-ACCESS accessible-for-notify
       STATUS current
       DESCRIPTION
        "Action code of the alert"
        ::= { scaleioAlert 4 }

-- 1.3.6.1.4.1.1139.101.1.5
        xGroups OBJECT IDENTIFIER ::= { xAlert 5 }


        -- 1.3.6.1.4.1.1139.101.1.5.1
        currentObjectGroup OBJECT-GROUP
            OBJECTS { xAlertSeverity,
                xAlertType,
                xAlertSourceObjectId,
                xAlertActionCode }
            STATUS current
            DESCRIPTION
                "x-MIB-V2 OBJECT-GROUP."
            ::= { xGroups 1 }

        -- 1.3.6.1.4.1.1139.101.1.5.2
        currentNotificationGroup NOTIFICATION-GROUP
            NOTIFICATIONS { xAEAlert }
            STATUS current
            DESCRIPTION
                "x-MIB-V2 NOTIFICATION-GROUP."
            ::= { xGroups 2 }


xAEAlert NOTIFICATION-TYPE
       OBJECTS { xAlertSeverity, xAlertType, xAlertSourceObjectId, xAlertActionCode }
       STATUS current
       DESCRIPTION "x Alert"
       ::= { x 1 }
END
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Don't import `DisplayString` from `RFC1213-MIB`. You are mixing `SMIv1` and `SMIv2`. Import `DisplayString` from `SNMPv2-TC` instead.
2. Try adding an intermediate `OBJECT IDENTIFIER` between you module identity and `xAlert`. I was able to get the warning for scalar's parent node must be simple node to go away by doing this.

   ```
   xMibObjects OBJECT IDENTIFIER ::= { x 1 }
   xAlert OBJECT IDENTIFIER ::= { xMibObjects 1 }
   ```

I don't have the text for your `Y-MIB`, so I couldn't complete the imports.